# Find the name of OS in which Jenkins is running?

Tags: azure, jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

I have my Jenkins installed on azure VM.

How can I find the OS of the machine in which Jenkins is installed from Jenkins ?

Comment: are you accessing it in a script or you want to see the os info???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to Managed Jenkins > System Information : Under that you can find a property with name: **os.name**

That should have the underlying OS name.